# Как вывести код в странице HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как вывести код ниже в странице HTML

```
const axios = require('axios');

let response = null;
new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        response = await axios.get(
            'https://api.binance.us/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=BTCUSD'
        );
    } catch (ex) {
        response = null;
        // error
        console.log(ex);
        reject(ex);
    }
    if (response) {
        // success
        const json = response.data;
        console.log(json);
        resolve(json);
    }
});
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А вообще, что не получается?

Comment: Я бы написал ответ, но нужно знать конкретный вопрос. Как и ЧТО вам нужно выводить? И куда?

Comment: Запустить это запрос с html страницы и ответ вывести на экран?

Answer (score 0):

> Как вывести код ниже в странице HTML

Сам код выводить нет никакого смысла... Другое дело вывести данные которые можно получить неким скриптом (кодом).

В твоем "примере" какая-то каша, т.ч. я покажу свой вариант того как можно данные получать и выводить.

Для каких-то конкретных рекомендаций для тебя - нужно знать какие данные к тебе будет приходить и как именно ты собираешься их показывать...

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
const os = document.querySelector('section')
test(url)
  .then(res => {
    res.forEach(o => {
      const html = `<article><h1>${o.title}</h1><p>${o.body}</p></article>`
      os.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
    })
  })
  .catch(console.log)

//
async function test(url) {
  let res = await fetch(url)
  res = await res.json()
  return res
}
```

```html
<section>
</section>
```